# Feature Extraction: 0%| | 0/25000 [00:00<?, ?it/s] Takes Forever and it never ends .... python ... dogsvs cats DL project

Tags: python

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

import os 

from random import shuffle 

from tqdm import tqdm

​

TRAIN_DIR = '/home/ajmal/Dogs vs cat/train'

TEST_DIR = '/home/ajmal/Dogs vs cat/test'

IMG_SIZE = 50

LR = 1e-3

CNN = 'dogsvscats-{}-{}-model'.format(LR, '2conv-basics')

​

​

def label_img(img):

    word_label = img.split('.')[-3]

    if word_label == 'cat':return[1,0]

    elif word_label == 'dog':return[0,1]

​

    

    

def create_train_data():

    training_data = []

    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):

        label = label_img(img)

        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)

        img = cv2.imread(TRAIN_DIR)

        img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))

        training_data.append([np.array(img),np.array(label)])

        shuffle(training_data)

        np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)

        return training_data

    

    

def process_test_data():

    testing_data = []

    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TEST_DIR)):

        path = os.path.join(TEST_DIR,img)

        img_num = img.split('.')[0]

        img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

        img = cv2.resize(img,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))

        testing_data.append([np.array(img),np.array(label)])

        

    shuffle(testing_data)

    np.save('test_data.npy',testing_data)

    return testing_data

​

train_data = create_train_data()

  0%|          | 0/25000 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

Comment: can you check your indentation? The code you posted looks like the return in create_train_data is inside the for loop. If that is the case, then it returns after the first iteration, and your program should terminate but the tqdm output stay the way you show. Does the program terminate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an indentation error, you shuffle and return inside the loop (in `create_train_data()`). Change it to:

```py
def create_train_data():

    training_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):

        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)

        img = cv2.imread(TRAIN_DIR)
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(img), np.array(label)])

    shuffle(training_data)
    np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)

    return training_data
```

(because of readability, Id recommend you not to put line-breaks everywhere)
I hope that solves your issue!